# Which compile flag enables “balloonexpr”?

Tags: installing

When loading a session file from another machine I
get errors of the form

```
E518: Unknown option: balloonexpr=
```

Which is one of the more obscure features of Vim that I
don’t seem to have compiled in. However, grepping the
output of Vim’s `configure` script doesn’t show any
directly related compile flag.

What does one have to do to enable the `balloonexpr`
option? This is on Vim version *patch 8.0.0134*.

Comment: Btw. someone powerful enough please create the tags ``balloonexpr`` and ``compile-options``, thanks.

Comment: `:h balloonexpr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That feature is shown by the 'balloon-eval' flag in the `:version` output. See `:h +feature-list` for the description of all flags and specifically `:h balloon-eval`

According to feature.h it is enabled for the following conditions:

```
  #if (defined(FEAT_GUI_MOTIF) || defined(FEAT_GUI_ATHENA) \
          || defined(FEAT_GUI_GTK) || defined(FEAT_GUI_W32)) \
          && (   ((defined(FEAT_TOOLBAR) || defined(FEAT_GUI_TABLINE)) \
                  && !defined(FEAT_GUI_GTK) && !defined(FEAT_GUI_W32)) \
              || defined(FEAT_SUN_WORKSHOP) \
              || defined(FEAT_NETBEANS_INTG) || defined(FEAT_EVAL))
  # define FEAT_BEVAL
```

i.e. basically when you use a supported Gui + the eval feature.